# Rocket.Chat: cannot perform readlinkat() on the mount namespace file descriptor of the init process: Permission denied

Tags: snap

(The original problem resolved itself after some update, but the problem remains that the installation does not work; edited question)

I am trying to install `rocketchat-server` on Ubuntu 16.04. According to https://rocket.chat/download, it suffices to run `snap install rocketchat-server` (which I run with `sudo`).

The installation finishes, but the server does not come up. The logfile says: `cannot perform readlinkat() on the mount namespace file descriptor of the init process: Permission denied`

I can find no indication on what to do about the problem.

---

**Original Question:**

I am trying to install `rocketchat-server` on Ubuntu 16.04. According to https://rocket.chat/download, it suffices to run `snap install rocketchat-server` (which I run with `sudo`). However, after downloading the snap, the process terminates, printing:

```
2017-03-18T16:32:46+01:00 INFO Waiting for restart...
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "core" snap if present (run hook "configure": 
-----
cannot bind-mount the mount namespace file /proc/11002/ns/mnt -> core.mnt: Permission denied
support process for mount namespace capture exited abnormally
-----)
```

I tried the same on my laptop where it installs and runs fine. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: This specific problem is resolved, but the server does not start after I run the `snap install`. The log shows the following: `cannot perform readlinkat() on the mount namespace file descriptor of the init process: Permission denied`.

Comment: Please join [this channel](https://open.rocket.chat/channel/ubuntu-snap) where the Rocket Chat lead (Aaron Ogle) should be able to resolve your problem. Write up the solution when you have it, edit your question, and mark your answer as accepted! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should update your kernel. I had the same issue, and I found this bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1709155

I use Ubuntu Server 14.04 at DigitalOcean, so I found the following information very useful:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-update-a-digitalocean-server-s-kernel
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

I was stuck with an older kernel. Once I updated it, my Rocket.Chat runs like a charm.